# Copied this code from the official arcade site but i get this error: AttributeError: module 'arcade' has no attribute 'Scene'

Tags: python, arcade

When I run my code I get

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Luke Coopman\Python\game2.py", line 226, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Luke Coopman\Python\game2.py", line 221, in main
    window.setup()
  File "c:\Users\Luke Coopman\Python\game2.py", line 66, in setup
    self.scene = arcade.Scene()
AttributeError: module 'arcade' has no attribute 'Scene'
```

I copied the code from here: https://arcade.academy/examples/platform_tutorial/step_08.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show the code you are using itself in your question, instead of a link?

Comment: I cant copy the code, it says that it is not properly formatted

Comment: But i didnt change anything i just copied the code, added images and ran it

Comment: It looks like the real "arcade" library is obscured by something else. What does a small program like `import arcade; print(arcade.VERSION)` output? It should be 2.5.7, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using Arcade `2.5.7` or older. [Scene](https://api.arcade.academy/en/2.6.0/api/sprite_scenes.html) class was introduced on version `2.6.0`. So you need to update your Arcade lib to the latest version.